Is the U.S Labor Market rolling over?
Good increase in jobs and reduction in unemployment in the U.S last week.
Since 2022, QUITS and the Employment Cost Index have been trending sharply lower though. Also savings are dwindled iirc. Will this halt consumer spending?
What are you thoughts on this with regards to the relationship between the 3, and the economy?
Is the Labor market actually not great and part time employment bumped it up?
https://fred.stlouisfed.org/graph/?g=1v9s8
https://fred.stlouisfed.org/graph/?g=1v9tp
